# Is there delete anchor point tool for multiple anchors in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tools, anchor-point

I'm looking for a way to remove multiple anchor points from path, but keppeing path intact. Now i select multiple points with lasso tool, then hit delete, then select 2 new end points and join them. but i'm looking for tool like (-) that deletes points but i don't need to rejoin it.

Comment: Hi Lesha, welcome to GDSE. I'm a bit confused by your question.. You named the tool and the shortcut to the tool in your question.. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: ...are you looking for a way to delete multiple points at the same time? Unlike the delete anchor point tool that only deletes one at at time?

Comment: yes, i select like 200 points with lasso tool and i need to remove them so other point on path stay connected

Comment: but if i delete these points and then join them by ctrl+j i get the same result every time

Comment: because i need to select two new endpoints manually and join command doesn't appear in actions when performed

Comment: Have you tried the Object > Path > Simplify tool? Not exactly what you're looking for in this question, but it might do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a tool. it called [VectorScribe](http://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/) from astute graphics and you can download a trial version from their site.

This tool have "the missing tools" that should be included in Illustrator. it have a tons of useful tools, but what I am thinking you are looking for is a tools called **`"Smart Remove Brush Tool"`**

[image]

As you can see from the animated GIF above it is just like the `simplify tool` in Illustrator but it is controlled visually and locally with a brush, not like the global fix effect as `simplify tool` in Illustrator.

Comment: some other useful ways to simplify your curve in Illustrator http://vectorboom.com/load/tips/techniques/some_ways_to_simplify_path_or_reduce_extra_points_in_illustrator/16-1-0-452

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Select the anchors you want to delete....

... hit the `Remove Selected Anchor Points` button on the control bar...

[image]

This will remove all of the selected anchor point with a single click and **not** break any path they are on. It *may* cause curves to be adjusted depending upon what *type* of anchor points you remove (smooth/corner).

Answer (score -1):

Select `Anchor Points`

`Object` - `Path` - `Remove Anchor Points`

Comment: Can you please add an screenshot showing the menu one has to select? It's easier to find it then ...